# Derive the PDF of the log-normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, logarithms, normal-distribution, exponential-function

If $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y = e^X$, find the PDF of $Y$ using the two methods:
(i) Find the CDF of of $Y$ and then differentiate. Use the notation $\Phi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ for the CDF and PDF of $X$ respectively. You may use the fact that $\phi(x) = \Phi'(x)$. 
So I'm not sure how to differentiate $\Phi\big(\dfrac{\ln x-\mu}{\sigma} \bigg)$ to get $\dfrac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^-\frac{(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$
(ii) Use the transformation formula.
I'm not sure where to even begin with this one.

Comment: For (i), just use the chain rule for differentiation, remembering that $$\frac{d}{dx}\Phi(g(x))=\phi(g(x))g'(x) ~~\mathrm{where}~~ \phi(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}.$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434453/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $Y=e^X$, then $\varphi^{-1}(Y)= \log Y$. Hence, $f_X (y) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{\log^2 y}{2}}$ and differentiate $|\frac{d \varphi^{-1}(Y)}{dy} | = |\frac{1}{Y}|$. Hence, the pdf of $Y$ is 
$$
h_{Y}(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{\log^2 y}{2}}\frac{1}{|y|}
$$

Comment: This is called function of the single random variable, that can probably be referred to as transformation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables

Comment: Could you possibly go into a little more detail? I.e. how did you get from $log Y$ to the following expression?

Comment: Just log both sides. Then take a derivative wrt to $y$

Comment: I still don't understand - it's the transition to the expression for $f_X(y)$ that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: OK, take the pdf of $X$ and replace $x$ with $x = \varphi^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: You appear to have combined (i) and (ii) into one, so I'm getting confused...

Comment: No, I didn't use CDF of $X$ anywhere and I didn't differentiate it either. I differentiated $X= \log Y$, which is necessary for the transformation formula.

Comment: Oh right, my mistake.