# $X\sim N(0,1)$, find probability density function of $Y=e^X$.

Tags: probability

$X\sim N(0,1)$, find probability density function of $Y=e^X$.

Define $\psi:=e^X$, since $\psi$ is a monotonic continues function then $\frac{f_X(X)}{|\psi'(X)|}=f_{\psi(X)}(X)=f_Y(Y)$.

$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}{ln(y)y}=f_Y
$

I am not sure that i can use this theorem.

Is it correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: We have $F_{Y}(x)=\mathbf{P}[e^{X}\leqslant x]$.

Comment: I know the other way, I try it with this specific theorem.

Comment: Well, there's not problem. In this case only you need to see that if $f_{X}(x)=e^{x}$ is increasing or decreasing on soport of $f_{X}(x)$.

Comment: @erez This specific theorem is called the Jacobian Transformation.

Comment: [Derive the PDF of the log-normal distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369681/derive-the-pdf-of-the-log-normal-distribution), https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434453/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use the Jacobian Transformation

$f_{Y}(y)=|\frac{dx}{dy}|f_{X}(x)$

You have $y=e^{x}\implies \ln(y)=x$ and  $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x}=y$.

And $f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^{2}}{2})$

So $f_{Y}(y)=\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{\ln^{2}(y)}{2})\,\,,\,y>0$

Answer (score 2):

With the substitution $x=g(y)$ we have $dx = g'(y) \, dy$, so
$$f(x) \, dx = f(g(y)) g'(y) \, dy
= f(\ln y) \frac{1}{y} \, dy
= \frac{1}{y} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(\ln y)^2/2} \, dy$$
which is the [PDF of the standard log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Probability_density_function).

Answer (score 2):

No it is not correct

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\log^2(x)/2}$$

It's a LogNormal density

Answer (score 1):

The cumulative probability function of $Y$ is :

$$P(Y\leq t) =P(e^X\leq t)=P(X\leq \ln(t))=\int_{-\infty}^{\ln(t)}f_X(u)du$$

since $f_Y (t) = \frac{d}{dt} P(Y\leq t)$, by the FTC and the chain rule you get:

$$f_Y(t)=\frac{f_X(\ln(t))}{t}$$

Using that $X\sim N(0,1)$

$$f_Y(t)=\frac{1}{t\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\ln(t)^2}{2}}$$